# Java Apache POI - Get Value of Cell to the Right of Cell Matching Regex?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have an Excel spreadsheet that is full of label cells to the left of corresponding value cells. Like this:

```
     E                  F
3    Invoice Number     "ABC123"
4    Issue Date         "2018-04-01"
5    Amount Due          298.43
```

I cannot rely on the values I want being in the same static cell location with each spreadsheet I process.

I want to use a regex to find the label cell (column E) that corresponds to the value I want (column F), then set the value to a variable.

I am refactoring into Java (using Apache POI library) legacy code originally written using Python. The Python code uses the following syntax to achieve the above goal:

```
for row in range(startrow, row+1):
    if str(rowdata[0].lower().find("invoice number")) > -1:
       invoice_number = rowdata[i+1]
```

I can't find equivalent functionality in the Apache POI documentation. 
A pseudocode example of what I'm trying to do:

```
String invoiceNumber;
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator;
while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    Row row = rowIterator.next();
    Iterator<Cell> = row.cellIterator();
    while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {
        if (cell.matches("invoice number") {
             invoiceNumber = cell + 1
        }
    }
}
```

Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator - you'll probably want to fetch by row/cell index rather than iterator but it could be done if needed if you take the iterator out of the for loop

Answer (score 1):

```
String invoiceNumber ;
    Iterator<Sheet> sheetIt = wb.sheetIterator();
    while (sheetIt.hasNext()) {
        Sheet sheet= sheetIt.next();
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();            
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIt = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIt.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIt.next();
                if(cell.getStringCellValue().equals("Invoice Number")) {
                    invoiceNumber=  row.getCell(cell.getColumnIndex()+1).getStringCellValue();

                }                   
            }               
        }
    }
```